# APS/DA: How to retrieve an url in correct format from BIM360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Following this tutorial for [Design Automation API for AutoCAD](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/) I get the expected result.
The goal is to use an existing drawing as input, stored in BIM360.
Therefore I have also a running example. In task 6 "Send WorkItem" I changed the input file and used as "url" parameter a drawing in that format:

```
"InputDwg": {
    "url": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/d96ca270-5f87-46dc-9330-xxxxxxxxxxxx.dwg",
    "verb": "get",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer {{dasApiToken}}"
    }
},
```

Question: How to retrieve that ObjectID for another drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information do you have about this "another drawing"? You can use the BIM360 API to enumerate drawings in a project and get their URN.

Comment: Ok, I checked the response of the API call

projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions

and there exists a "relationships/storage" section and the "relationships/storage/data/id" contains the expected format for the dwg:

"storage": {
  "data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/5e66d5ce-75e8-4eeb-a4c5-xxxxxxxxxxxx.dwg"
  }

This answers my question. Thank you for the food for thought.